# Spring @ComponentScan annotation

Tags: spring

Why do we use @ComponentScan annotation in spring ? I am not being able to figure out the exact difference between context:componentscan in xml file  and @ComponentScan annotations in java and how to use them in case of classes which have been annotated with @Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there is no difference.

[@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) - Used with `@Configuration` classes, for example, when you have java-based configurations for Spring.

It provides  support parallel with Spring XML's `<context:component-scan>` element. The purpose of those two are exactly the same - to scan spring components.

Answer (score 0):

But there is one advantage of xml based configuration - you don't need to compile your java code. When you added some package under `<context:component-scan>` then you don't need to compile java source code. Place the xml configuration file in your server and restart it.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where I would want to do this or even be able to do this. What code are you adding that isn't referenced by your existing code yet you still want scanned? Configuring Spring via Java is preferable because errors in bean creation are found at compile time. A typo in an XML configuration file won't be found until the app is deployed.  I've found that Java config is far easier to maintain as well.